# how do I save order details using API v2 in Squareup Payment Gateway?

Tags: api, payment, square-connect

I am using this method to make payment https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form
but I wanted to save oders details as well as customer details
using the above method I am able to see only custom amount I transaction details on sqareup

Comment: This is now possible: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/building-for-an-omni-channel-business-with-squares-apis-has-never-been-easier-3b5e0977741a

Answer (score 0):

Use the Orders endpoints to save itemization information for your e-commerce transactions: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/building-for-an-omni-channel-business-with-squares-apis-has-never-been-easier-3b5e0977741a